# BoxCox Transformation in auto.arima(): Does it also transform the residuals?

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using the `auto.arima()` function in the forecast package in R.  I performed a Box-Cox transformation (lambda = 0.02492832, if you're curious).  My data are on the order of 10^9 and is exhibiting increasing variance after differencing twice, so I think B-C is appropriate.  Strangely, the residuals are on the order of 10^-2.  Not sure if I have discovered a crystal ball or if I'm missing something in the way residuals are calculated when using a B-C transformation in `auto.arima()`.  Are the residuals also transformed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residuals are on the scale of the transformed data. If you want to compute data - fitted instead, use `fitted()` to obtain the fitted values.

Answer (score 0):

If the variance is equal to k, the lambda component of the residual is the coefficient of k. Thus lambda(k)=10^9.
There is something missing in the box-cox transformation which is generating increasing variances.
It is the forecast ''k''.
Yes, the residuals are transformed. We simply 10^-2 to the forecast k.
This value generates a new forecast.